# Finding Longest Set of Consecutive Characters in a String using Java

Tags: java, string, count

I know I'm missing a line, I believe the sudo for it would be: for i = 0 to str.length - 1:

I put that line where I thought it should go, but I'm not sure how I would write it? Pretty new to this, any help appreciated!

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    c = new Console ();

    String size;

    c.print ("Enter a string: ");
    size = c.readString ();

    String answer = sizeOfLargestGroup (size);

    c.println (answer);
} // main method


private static String sizeOfLargestGroup (String size)

{
    maxCount = 1;
    currCount = 1;
    for i = 0 to str.length - 1:
    if (currCount > maxCount)
        maxCount = currCount;
    if (str [i] == str [i + 1])
        currCount++;
    else
        currCount = 1;
    return maxCount;

}
```

Comment: search google for *java for loop* - definitely not the syntax you are using

Comment: do you mean use a loop instead of a method?

Comment: do you know what `for` does? it loops

Comment: where is your str[] array? also are you trying to display something like abcdefg?

Comment: Not allowed to use arrays, in a comp sci class at school. And I'm trying to display whatever a user inputs

Comment: So I'm trying to have it if someone entered aaarrrffff it would display 4, because the longest streak of consecutive numbers is 4 f's

Comment: but you are using an array with an identifier of str,also please change your method to public for the main method to be able to use it

Comment: Oh..yeah, just saw that, sorry, really new to this,  I changed the method to public though, took out the array. Had someone helping me with this before, any idea how I would go about accomplishing this goal still?

Comment: was it always consecutive entered String or not? because if not I have an idea you are going to need an array e.g. it is aaaarrrrfffff or rraafafaffff

Comment: Yeah, it's always consecutive

Answer (score 0):

consider my following answer, I declare 2 int in the method, one to know how many letter and one to know which is bigger

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter a string");
                String mySize=scan.nextLine();
                int answer=sizeOfLargestGroup(mySize);
                System.out.println(answer);
            }
            public static int sizeOfLargestGroup (String size)
            {
                int myCharInt=1;//get the character
                int myCurrent=0;//get the largest myCharInt
                for(int i=0;i<size.length()-1;++i)
                {

                    if(size.charAt(i)==size.charAt(i+1))
                        myCharInt++;

                    else
                        myCharInt=1;
                    if(myCurrent<myCharInt)//test the current value of myCharInt if it is largest switch it to the current value of myCurrent
                    myCurrent=myCharInt;

                }

                return myCurrent;


            }
```